# Como executar uma inserção apenas uma vez via javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma situação onde preciso inserir uma unica vez uma div em um bloco via jQuery, existe alguma função já definida que garanta que esse bloco ira ser inserido uma unica vez? Sem eu ter que fazer o check com if

```
if (!jQuery('.product').parents('.product-info').has('.quickreview').length {
    jQuery('.product').parents('.product-info').prepend("<div class="quickreview"></div>");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu utilizaria uma lógica para isso, criaria uma bool para ver se elá já está criada, se passar pelo if uma vez ela se torna false e não entrará mais nele

Dessa maneira:

```
var needToCreate = true;

if (!jQuery('.product').parents('.product-info').has('.quickreview').length && needToCreate) {
    jQuery('.product').parents('.product-info').prepend("<div class="quickreview"></div>");
    needToCreate = false;
}
```

Comment: O parentese faltando foi culpa da pessoa que editou o post do rapaz, no original tinha o parentese do if colocado corretamente.

Comment: A obrigado por esclarecer!

Answer (score 1):

Veja se com o método [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) te ajuda:

```js
$("#btn1").one("click", function(){                   // executa apenas uma vez
  $("#local1").prepend("<p>Qualquer coisa - uma vez</p>");
})

$("#btn2").on("click", function(){                   // executa varias vezes
  $("#local2").prepend("<p>Qualquer coisa - mais de uma vez</p>");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn1">inserir</button>  
<div id="local1"></div>
<hr>
<button id="btn2">inserir</button>  
<div id="local2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se pretende perceber quando o DOM é alterado deve utilizar [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Este permite definir um callback que executa sempre que houver uma alteração num determinado elemento e respetivos descendentes.

```js
document.getElementById("inserir").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("conteudo").innerHTML = "<div class='product'>Produto</div>";
});

//no pai do que pretende escutar as alterações
const targetNode = document.getElementById('conteudo'); 
const config = { childList: true, subtree: true};

const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList) {
  for (let mutation of mutationsList) { //para cada uma das alterações no DOM
    if (mutation.type == 'childList') { //se afeta os filhos
      const removedIds = [...mutation.removedNodes].map(x => x.id); //apanhar os id's
      if (!removedIds.includes("teste")){ //se o id existe é porque foi inserido
        console.log("teste já inserido");
      }
    }
  }
}); 

observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

```html
<div id="conteudo">
  <div id="teste">Div teste aqui</div>
</div>
<button id="inserir">Uma única vez</div>
```